# Reverse sentence in C

Tags: c, reverse

I tried to find something matched to my needs but I didn't.

Could someone help me fix my code to successfully reverse a sentence (from: "my name is" to "is name my" for example).
Please without functions and pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0, end, count=0, sumletters=0;
    char str[1000], strrev[1000];

    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);//get string from user

    sumletters = strchr(str, '\0') - str - 1;//find the last characters in string
    while (sumletters) {
        end = sumletters= strchr(str, '\0') - str - 1;
        while (str[sumletters] != ' '){
            //find the number letters of the last word and enter to counter
            sumletters--;
        }

        for (i = 0; sumletters!=end; i++, sumletters++) {
            //enter every leters from the last word to new string 
            strrev[i] = str[sumletters + 1];
            str[sumletters + 1] = '\0';//dros the leters that already copy
        }

    }

    puts(str);
    puts(strrev);


}
```

Comment: C without pointers is like a car without wheels, or Stack Overflow without internet connection...

Comment: Have you ever thought of using `strtok`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read your sentence from the tail end. Read till you hit a whitespace. Then copy it letter by letter into the new string. Repeat this.

---

Now this is not a code completion service but I am giving you a rough idea [Here](https://github.com/saksham36/Doubts/blob/master/5.c). That code is incomplete so I would suggest you try harder yourself

---

One more thing

Replace `fgets` with `scanf("%[^\n]s", ...)`

`fgets` will read "who am i" as {'w','h','o',' ','a','m',' ','i','\n','\0'}

Answer (score 0):

Start scanning the string from back till you find a `' '`, store its position to start next time from this index. Now from this location move forward to till you find another `' '` or the string ends and keep assigning the chars to the new reverse array. repeat these steps till you reach the beginning of the original string.

```
char str[] = "This a sample string";
const int l = strlen(str);
char rev[l];
int i = 0, j, k = l-1;

while(i < l) {
    j = k; // starting point is k
    for(; str[j] != ' ' && j >= 0; j--); // moving j from right to left till ' ' found
    k = j-1; j++;
    for(; j < l && str[j] != ' '; j++, i++) { 
        rev[i] = str[j];
    }
    if(i < l)
        rev[i] = ' '; i++;
}
```

Output: `string sample a This`

**Steps envolved in parsing a single word**:

`i = 0, k = 8, j = k;`

```
   str          rev
......................
Hello Foo            
        ^     ^
        j     i
```

`j = 7, i = 0 // j--`

```
   str          rev
......................
Hello Foo            
       ^      ^
       j      i
```

`j = 6, i = 0 // j--`

```
   str          rev
......................
Hello Foo            
      ^       ^
      j       i
```

`j = 5, i = 0, k = j-1 // j--`

```
   str          rev
......................
Hello Foo            
     ^        ^
     j        i
```

`j = 6, i = 0 // j++`

```
   str          rev
......................
Hello Foo     F       
      ^       ^
      j       i
```

`j = 7, i = 1 // j++, i++`

```
   str          rev
......................
Hello Foo     Fo      
       ^       ^
       j       i
```

`j = 7, i = 2 // j++, i++`

```
   str          rev
......................
Hello Foo     Foo       
        ^       ^
        j       i
```

`j = 8, i = 3 // j++, i++`

```
   str          rev
......................
hello Foo     Foo       
         ^       ^
         j       i
```

Above process will repeat till `i < l`

**Note**: assuming the words are separated with a single `' '` char.

Comment: hi. thanks. i  almost sucssed but the rules is to accept ' ' and '   ' ('space' and 'tab' for perceive).  is my code changeable for that?    
 

 (i cant send here my code) 

}